# Find a Class object's Item with Maximum character count in a User Defined List

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, linq, max

I am new to the LINQ, I have got one scenario where I am stuck to do a task in single expression rather than looping.

In a Custom class array and within that array a specific string parameter maximum length?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
        foreach (CultureInfo ci in cinfo)
        {
            sb.Append(ci.Name + "," + ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + "," + ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName + "," + ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName + "," + ci.DisplayName + "," + ci.EnglishName + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        lb.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
        txtData.Text = sb.ToString();
```

here *cinfo* is the collection and I want to find out the element in the whole array which has maximum character in **Name** parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by the length of `Name` then take the first:

```
var cultureWithLongestName = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Length)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go about doing something like that is to order by the length and take the first element. We can do that like so:

```cs
var elementWithLongestName = collection.OrderByDescending(e => e.Name.Length).First();
```

HOWEVER, sorting with `OrderByDescending` gives you `O(nlog(n))` time complexity (it uses Quicksort). We can do better! we can solve this with linear time (`O(n)`):

### Using .NET 5.0 or below

Unfortunately, until .NET 6.0 (currently in preview) there is no built-in LINQ operator that finds a maximum element by one of its properties. There are two ways we can achieve this anyway:

##### Using vanilla LINQ

We can find the maximum length in the collection, and then find an element with that length:

```cs
var longestNameLength = collection.Select(e => e.Name.Length).Max();
var elementWithLongestName = collection.First(e => e.Name.Length == longestNameLength);
```

One downside of this approach (besides being more verbose) is that we're enumerating the same collection twice. In your case, that's fine because the source collection is a simple in-memory array. If the source collection was a more complicated `IEnumerable` (like a collection that lazily loads items from a database), it may be a good idea to turn it into an in-memory collection first by using `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

##### Using MoreLinq

You can use the popular package [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) to achieve what you asked for:

```
var elementWithLongestName = collection.MaxBy(e => e.Name.Length);
```

### Using .NET 6.0 and above

In this version, the `MaxBy` operator (that does exactly what you need) is included out of the box and there is no need to use a third-party library. You can just write:

```
var elementWithLongestName = collection.MaxBy(e => e.Name.Length);
```

NOTE: a stable release of .NET 6.0 is scheduled for November 2021.

Comment: Thank you very much for putting up the right solution and also advanced.